# Excel and IE11 VBA Automation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA and i'm trying to automate a web Explorer navigation but with many difficolties. I've composed a script that navigate into a web page and search for a code. the result is a table ("table") with one row that contains the searched item ("TCKNodanSorgula.aspx?tckno=27497556158") displayed as a link to another page. Here the code of that table:

```html
<div class="table">

 <span id="MainContent_lbl_YakinBilgi">
   <div class="th">
      <div class="tdmini">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="td">T.C. Kimlik No</div>
      <div class="tdmidi">B.S. No</div> 
      <div class="td">Yakınlık</div> 
      <div class="td">Adı</div> 
      <div class="td">Doğum Tarihi</div> 
      <div class="td">Durumu</div> 
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
 <div class="tr"> 
  <div class="tdmini">
   <a href="TCKNodanSorgula.aspx?tckno=27461667396" title="Sorgula">
    <img alt="Sorgula" src="images/openLink.gif">
   </a>
  </div> 
      <div class="td">27461077396</div> 
      <div class="tdmidi">34</div> 
      <div class="td">Kendisi</div> 
      <div class="td">SEVGİ</div> 
      <div class="td">25/10/1960</div> 
      <div class="td">Açık</div> 
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          </div>
        <div class="tr"> 
  <div class="tdmini">
   <a href="TCKNodanSorgula.aspx?tckno=27497556158" title="Sorgula">
    <img alt="Sorgula" src="images/openLink.gif">
 </a>
       </div>
     <div class="td">27497076158</div> 
     <div class="tdmidi">19</div> 
     <div class="td">Babası</div> 
     <div class="td">ŞEKİ</div> 
     <div class="td">01/12/1932</div> 
     <div class="td">Ölüm</div> 
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
       <div class="tr"> 
 <div class="tdmini">
  <a href="TCKNodanSorgula.aspx?tckno=27470145004" title="Sorgula">
   <img alt="Sorgula" src="images/openLink.gif">
  </a>
        </div> 
    <div class="td">27470077004</div> 
    <div class="tdmidi">30</div> 
    <div class="td">Annesi</div> 
    <div class="td">YÜKEL</div> 
    <div class="td">11/09/1937</div> 
    <div class="td">Açık</div> 
    <div style="clear: both;">
 </div>
     </div>
  </span>
                
</div>
```

Here my code:

```
For Each tık In ob.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If tık.innertext = href Then
        tık.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next tık
```

I can find but I can't execute the code in order to press the second href button. I'm using IE 11.

Thanks for your patience!.

Comment: yes because you `exit for` after the first click, so the loop stops here. Remove it and put your code that handles everything that should be run after a click instead of `exit for`

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: Sorry, unresolved

Comment: "*Sorry, unresolved*" isn't useful to anyone. If you really expect help from anyone I suggest you to [edit] your question and add exactly where your code fails and describe *detailed* what you are trying to achieve. Your question is very unclear (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
y = 0
For Each ele In ob.document.getElementById("MainContent_lbl_YakinBilgi").getElementsByTagName("a")
    y = y + 1
    If y = 2 Then
    Cells(i, 34).Value = ele.outerHTML
    End If

Next ele
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.